# What is the etymology of the て-form?

Tags: grammar

What are the origins of the て-form? Was its meaning when it initially appeared different from what it is now?

Answer (score 3):

The connective particle *-te* is derived from the continuative form of the lower bigrade perfective auxiliary *-tu*.

## Syntactic evolution

The distribution of the auxiliary *-tu* (including its continuative form *-te*) was that it appeared after the continuative form of verbs (i.e., it did **not** appear after *-ku* in adjectives), which is a restriction all auxiliaries share.

At some point, *-te* lost its explicit perfective function and became reanalyzed as a connective particle, and at that point its distribution became much more relaxed, allowing it to appear after anything which was in the continuative form (i.e., including adjectives).

## Semantics

As to why the perfective auxiliary *-tu* was what ended up evolving into the connective particle instead of something else, I think it is a fairly natural choice – the perfective semantics (i.e., that the verb has "completed") is still present in a number of interpretations of *-te*, in the sense that the verb marked by *-te* is completed either before or in parallel with the following verb.

Comment: Would it be possible to illustrate your answer with an example? It would make your answer much more accessible to people like me who make archaic forms a lower priority out of necessity but would stil like to learn. (I was very successful researching auxiliary つ on the web.)

Comment: @Tim You can find 助動詞「つ」 in a 古語辞典.  For example, see the second entry for つ here on Weblio: http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A4  　By the way, the 活用形 are ｛て・て・つ・つる・つれ・てよ｝.  I'm not sure why Weblio doesn't list them, but my 旺文社古語辞典 does.